# Wordcountaddin shows NA_Real

Tags: r, r-markdown, na, word-count

I was just wondering what could be happening here.
I tried reinstalling the package, but for some reason, wordcountaddin by benmarwick is still producing `NA_Real_` in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You might try `stringi::stri_extract`,

```
md <- system.file(package="plyr", "NEWS.md")

wordcountaddin::text_stats(md)[3] |>
  stringi::stri_extract(regex='[0-9]+') |> as.numeric()
# [1] 2748
```

**however,** the package (version 0.3.0.9000) has already a builtin word count function.

```
wordcountaddin::word_count(md)
# [1] 2748
```

If you still get `NA`, there might be an issue with your .Rmd file (e.g. only code, language package not available).